# Android Spinner

Tags: android

I am having three spinner. I wanna to display today date in 1st spinner and current month in 2nd spinner and year in 3rd spinner when new Activity started.. Like this 30 12 2010

Comment: The odd this is, there's no question (or even a question mark) in this...

Comment: First, you should be clear with your question

Answer (score 8):

use [`DatePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) instead spinners.